# Canvas collision detection

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, collision-detection

As you can see there I've done some collisions in the middleish part... 
That doesn't the console log !HIT! so it doesn't work. I want that boxes collide with player. I've read help everywhere tried their codes and no success. If you could fix it and maybe comment the parts you did with your name/nickname; Since this code is going for a *Open-source-Game* of mine. Everyone can edit it and stuff. The game currently has sounds a box that jumps and flies. And also if you could make it so that player could stay and stand on the boxes while you are at it :D.. for that you do

```
if(whateverthenameofyourcollisiondertectionthenis){
 player.jumping = false,
 player.VelY = 0
}
```

Or something like that I think...
I started with javascript few days ago so I dont know so much about it...

So my code goes like this:

```
(function() {
    var requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame;
    window.requestAnimationFrame = requestAnimationFrame;
})();
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    width = 1600,
    height = 900,
    player = {
      x : width/2,
      y : height - 5,
      width : 5,
      height : 5,
      speed: 5,
      velX: 0,
      velY: 0,
      jumping: false,
      nofly: true,
      colission: false,
      left: false,
      right: false,

    },
    keys = [],
    friction = 0.8,
    gravity = 0.2;

    var boxes = []
 // dimensions
boxes.push({
    x: Math.floor((Math.random() * 1400) + 1),
    y: Math.floor((Math.random() * 895) + 1),
    width: 200,
    height: 5,
});
boxes.push({
    x: Math.floor((Math.random() * 1400) + 1),
    y: Math.floor((Math.random() * 895) + 1),
    width: 200,
    height: 5,
});
boxes.push({
    x: Math.floor((Math.random() * 1400) + 1),
    y: Math.floor((Math.random() * 895) + 1),
    width: 200,
    height: 5,
});
boxes.push({
    x: Math.floor((Math.random() * 1400) + 1),
    y: Math.floor((Math.random() * 895) + 1),
    width: 200,
    height: 5,
});
boxes.push({
    x: Math.floor((Math.random() * 1400) + 1),
    y: Math.floor((Math.random() * 895) + 1),
    width: 200,
    height: 5,
});
boxes.push({
    x: Math.floor((Math.random() * 1400) + 1),
    y: Math.floor((Math.random() * 895) + 1),
    width: 200,
    height: 5,
});
boxes.push({
    x: Math.floor((Math.random() * 1400) + 1),
    y: Math.floor((Math.random() * 895) + 1),
    width: 200,
    height: 5,
});


canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;

function update(){
  // check keys
    if (keys[38] || keys[32] || keys[87]) {
        // up arrow or space or W
      if(!player.jumping){
      console.log("jump")
       player.jumping = true;
       player.velY = -player.speed*3;
       document.getElementById('Jump').play();
      }
    }
    if (keys[39] || keys[68]) {
        // right arrow or D
        if(!player.right){ player.left = false
        if (player.velX < player.speed) {                         
           player.velX++;
        console.log("Right")           
       }
       }
    }     
    if (keys[37] || keys[65]) {         
        // left arrow   
          if(!player.left){ player.right = false
          if (player.velX > -player.speed) {
           player.velX--;
           console.log("Left")
       }
       }
   }
    if (keys[40] || keys[83]) {
        // down arrow or S
        if(player.jumping){
           player.velY++;
           player.valX;
           console.log("Down!")
       }
   }
   if (keys[13]) {
        // Enter
        player.jumping = true
        if(player.nofly){
        console.log("Flap!")
        player.velY = -player.speed*1;
        document.getElementById('Flap').play();
        player.nofly = false;
        setTimeout(function(){player.nofly = true;},600);}
     }
    player.velX *= friction;

    player.velY += gravity;

    player.x += player.velX;
    player.y += player.velY;

    if (player.x >= width-player.width) {
    player.right = true
    console.log("Wall!")
        player.x = width-player.width;
    } else if (player.x <= 0) {         
        player.x = 0;
        console.log("Wall!")    
            player.left = true
    }    

    if(player.y >= height-player.height){
        player.y = height - player.height;
        player.jumping = false;
        console.log("Ground!")
    }

  ctx.clearRect(0,0,width,height);
  ctx.fillStyle = "white";
ctx.beginPath();

for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
    ctx.rect(boxes[i].x, boxes[i].y, boxes[i].width, boxes[i].height);
}

ctx.fill();
  ctx.fillStyle = "GreenYellow";
  ctx.fillRect(player.x, player.y, player.width, player.height);

    //if(player.x = boxes[i].x - boxes[i].width &&
     //  player.y = boxes[i].y - boxes[i].height){player.velY = 0}

     if (boxes.push.x < player.x + player.width &&
        boxes.push.x + boxes.push.width > player.x &&
        boxes.push.y < player.y + player.height &&
        boxes.push.y + boxes.push.height > player.y)
            { player.colission = true; console.log("!HIT!")}

    else    { player.colission = false }

    if  (player.colission)  { player.velY = 0, console.log("Ohnoes we must stop")}


  requestAnimationFrame(update);
}


document.body.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    keys[e.keyCode] = true;
});

document.body.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
    keys[e.keyCode] = false;
});

window.addEventListener("load",function(){
    update();
});
function click(x,y){
    if(keys[38]){
    var ev = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
    var el = document.elementFromPoint(x,y);
    ev.initMouseEvent(
        "click",
        true /* bubble */, true /* cancelable */,
        window, null,
        x, y, player.x, player.y, /* coordinates */
        false, false, false, false, /* modifier keys */
        0 /*left*/, null
    );
    el.dispatchEvent(ev);
}
}
```

Comment: And what sort of boundary boxes were you planning to use for the player?

Comment: Can you create jsfiddle with working code? It seems that it does not work at all.

Comment: Deele This is suposed to be opened in browser with HTML code And Evan Knowles Bottom and sides prevent player from falling out of the canvas Link to whole game code download with recources and stuff can be found here: http://osrc-game.weebly.com/

Comment: Thanks alot... solved this by my self...